# Query to find customers orders in last 3 months are more than average number(count) of orders placed in the district

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which have columns- **customer_id**, **order_id**, **order_value**, **city** and **Date**. I need to find the following

The average number of orders in the district needs to be calculated at customer level.

**Example**: Three customers in a district named as 'xyz' have placed below number of orders

**CUSTOMER**|**ORDER_COUNT**

CUS1    | 5

CUS2    | 2

CUS3    |3

I need to find the average for each district comprising of **count of orders** in this case **cus1(5)**, **cus2(2)**, **cus3(3)** which is **3.3**

please help me on how do i move ahead with the query.. Thanks

Comment: start with the `select` and `from` keywords

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: @ahmed its postgre sql but i have been working in mysql too

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: @Hridikalpa What is so hard to add the postgre tag to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You may perform two levels of aggregation, in the first one find the count of orders grouped by city, customer_id, and in the second one find the average of that count grouped by city.

```
select city, AVG(cn) avg_orders_count
from
(
  select customer_id, city, count(*) cn
  from orders_table
  group by customer_id, city
) T
where city='xyz'
group by city
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/L7vVr2du).